# exited on signal 11 xhprof

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, xhprof

I have a big problem. I installed php5 extension `XHprof` on server (Ubuntu 14.04), and when I try to use it I have the `502 Bad Gateway`. Logs of nginx are empty, and in php-fpm log I have this:

```
[17-Jul-2017 19:20:25] WARNING: [pool www] child 8944 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 16.428915 seconds from start
```

In my script I wrote this:

```
if( extension_loaded( 'xhprof' ) ){
    if( function_exists( 'xhprof_enable' ) ){
        xhprof_enable( XHPROF_FLAGS_CPU + XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY );
        echo 'OK!';
    }
}
```

If I comment line with xhprof_enable(), it prints `OK!` and works correctly. So extension `xhprof` loaded and function `xhprof_enable()` exists (available). And `phpinfo()` show that `xhprof` exists. What can I do? It is very important.

Sorry for my English :) I know it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue see [xhprof issue #45](https://github.com/phacility/xhprof/issues/45) and [PHP bug #67997](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67997).

There's no official fix, the project seems to be inactive, it didn't had a release for over 4 years.

However you can workaround it by calling `xhprof_enable()` with `XHPROF_FLAGS_NO_BUILTINS`:

```
xhprof_enable(XHPROF_FLAGS_NO_BUILTINS);
```